# python string not writing to a file

Tags: python, file

this function is being called by the way

the file is correct 'paragraphs.txt'

but when it runs it finishes with no errors but doesn't write anything to the file

git files
file with problem:
https://github.com/K-972/english_helper

write to file test:
https://github.com/K-972/file-write-test

```
def petal_function():
    type_of_petal = input("""
enter number of what you want
  1: comparing ideas sources a and b
  2: how a character is presented
  3: how a them is presented in a poem""")

    if type_of_petal == '1':
        print('source A\n')
        idea = input('enter idea to explore')
        technique = input('enter technique to explore')
        quote = input('enter quote to explode')
        zoom_in_word = input('enter word to zoom in on')
        wordclass = input('enter word class of word')
        feeling = input('enter feeling created in the readers head')
        why_it_creates_the_feeling = input('why is the feeling created')
        print('\nsource B\n')
        technique_2 = input('enter another technique to explore')
        quote_2 = input('enter another quote to explode')
        zoom_in_word_2 = input('enter word to zoom in on')
        wordclass_2 = input('enter word class of word')
        image_constructed = input('enter image constructed in the readers head')
        why_it_creates_the_feeling_2 = input('enter why is the feeling created')


        petal = (f"""In source A the idea of {idea} is presented through the use of {technique} this is evident in the quote \'{quote}\'.
the {wordclass} \'{zoom_in_word}\' create\'s a {feeling} feeling in the reader\'s head and presents the idea of {idea} because
{why_it_creates_the_feeling}. However in source B the idea of {idea} is presented through the use of {technique_2} this is
shown in the quote \'{quote_2}\'. the {wordclass_2} \'{zoom_in_word_2}\' create\'s a {image_constructed} image in the reader\'s 
head and presents the idea of {idea} because {why_it_creates_the_feeling_2}.\n""")

        file = open('paragraphs.txt', 'a')
        file.write(petal)
```

i have wrote a script separately to test writing to a file and it worked so i don't know why this isn't

Comment: This will open the file _in the current directory_.  When you check the file after running the program, are you sure you're looking in the right directory?

Comment: You aren't closing the file, so the data you wrote may remain in internal buffers, rather than actually being flushed out to the disk.  It's better to use `with open(...):`, as that guarantees that the file will be closed when that block of code finishes.

Comment: Show, don't tell. You say the function is called, include the function call in the code. You say something happens when you run, show us what input results in that. Also, simplify your problem to be just the essence of it - most of your code is just moving strings around. Have you tried writing a simple `'Hello world'` to a file and see if you have the same problem?

Comment: @jasonharper unless the file gets accessed by something else outside the script, the file handle will be closed as the script terminates. The real problem is that OP isn't showing us how they are running or calling this. You're right though that putting everything in a context manager is a good idea, and *guarantees* the file is closed after the block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I run your code like this:

```
def petal_function():
    type_of_petal = input("""
enter number of what you want
  1: comparing ideas sources a and b
  2: how a character is presented
  3: how a them is presented in a poem""")

    if type_of_petal == '1':
        print('source A\n')
        idea = input('enter idea to explore')
        technique = input('enter technique to explore')
        quote = input('enter quote to explode')
        zoom_in_word = input('enter word to zoom in on')
        wordclass = input('enter word class of word')
        feeling = input('enter feeling created in the readers head')
        why_it_creates_the_feeling = input('why is the feeling created')
        print('\nsource B\n')
        technique_2 = input('enter another technique to explore')
        quote_2 = input('enter another quote to explode')
        zoom_in_word_2 = input('enter word to zoom in on')
        wordclass_2 = input('enter word class of word')
        image_constructed = input('enter image constructed in the readers head')
        why_it_creates_the_feeling_2 = input('enter why is the feeling created')


        petal = (f"""In source A the idea of {idea} is presented through the use of {technique} this is evident in the quote \'{quote}\'.
the {wordclass} \'{zoom_in_word}\' create\'s a {feeling} feeling in the reader\'s head and presents the idea of {idea} because
{why_it_creates_the_feeling}. However in source B the idea of {idea} is presented through the use of {technique_2} this is
shown in the quote \'{quote_2}\'. the {wordclass_2} \'{zoom_in_word_2}\' create\'s a {image_constructed} image in the reader\'s 
head and presents the idea of {idea} because {why_it_creates_the_feeling_2}.\n""")

        file = open('paragraphs.txt', 'a')
        file.write(petal)


petal_function()
```

And enter `'1'` through `'14'` as input, the script writes a `paragraphs.txt` containing the following:

```
In source A the idea of 2 is presented through the use of 3 this is evident in the quote '4'.
the 6 '5' create's a 7 feeling in the reader's head and presents the idea of 2 because
8. However in source B the idea of 2 is presented through the use of 9 this is
shown in the quote '10'. the 12 '11' create's a 13 image in the reader's 
head and presents the idea of 2 because 14.
```

So, your problem cannot be reproduced. Also, it's effective the same as this:

```
def petal_function():
    type_of_petal = input('Enter a 1 or something else: ')

    if type_of_petal == '1':
        petal = 'Hello world'

        file = open('paragraphs.txt', 'a')
        file.write(petal)


petal_function()
```

And that works just fine as well (appending the text to the file if it exists, creating it otherwise).

You're probably not looking for the file in the correct location. Try adding this to the start of your script, and see what it says:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

That's where you should be looking for the file that was written.

Also, probably unrelated to your actual problem, as pointed out in the comments, to ensure a file is written and properly closed, use a context manager:

```
with open('paragraphs.txt') as f:
    f.write(petal)
```